# ¿Cómo puedo redirigir usuarios desde un login con nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

archivo route.index

```
//local es la estrategia de autenticacion
//dashboard muestra el perfil del usuario creado

router.post('/login',(req,res,next)=> {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect:'/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }) (req, res, next);

});
```

El  problema es que no consigo hacerlo para mas de un usuario, los puedo registrar y loguear pero no los puedo redirigir a diferentes vistas...

Answer (score 0):

Tomado de la documentación de [`passportjs`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/).

```
app.post('/login',

  passport.authenticate('local'),
  //Aquí te falta la coma y esta función

  function(req, res) {
    // Si esta función es llamada, la autenticación es válida. 
    // `req.user` contiene al usuario autenticado. 
    res.redirect('/dashboard);
  });
```

Alternativamente lo puedes usar con un middleware:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate(
     'local', 
      { 
         successRedirect: '/dashboard',
         failureRedirect: '/login'
      }
  )
);
```

Hay que notar que se omite `(req, res, next)`.